# Yii2 Logout Event not fired

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to attach a logout event on user logout, but without success.

```
// after user login...
Yii::$app->user->on(\yii\web\User::EVENT_AFTER_LOGOUT, function ($e) {
    // some code...
});

// somewhere else
Yii::$app->user->logout();

// I expected the event to be fired after the above call...
```

Am I missing something?

EDIT:

EVENT_BEFORE_LOGIN / EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN are fired, but EVENT_BEFORE_LOGOUT / EVENT_AFTER_LOGOUT are not.

I'm totally confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listening for logout event in Yii 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384168/listening-for-logout-event-in-yii-2)

Comment: @stig-js it is not duplicating. The answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: @nevermind check the above mentioned question again, I have added my answer.

Comment: @Tom - Sorry, but I couldn't see the difference between my example. Accessing app->user will call the user component no matter where you put it, right?. In addition why EVENT_BEFORE_LOGIN/EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN are fired, but the logout events aren't?

Comment: @nevermind Can you show more code, so I can understand how does it work on your site? It should be working. You might have some bad code in the event handler or something else somwhere. This is the condition for  calling afterLogout: `($identity !== null && $this->beforeLogout($identity)) ` You might have not set the identity or your beforelogout returns false

Comment: @Tom - sorry I couldn't share the code, the project is private, but I still can't understand what is the difference between your answer and Yasky one in the similar question.

Comment: @nevermind lol I see youa re not the only one, someone already downvoted it... not eve worth trying to help. If you look closely Yasky is assignint the event to the user **model** not the **component**

Comment: @Tom - In my example I use the user component and it doesn't work.

Comment: @nevermind yes that is why I would need to see more of your code to find the issue. Not sure why you couldnt share couple of lines of code, I doubt anyone could "steal" your project idea from several lines of basic yii code..

Comment: I see there has been some talk about me here (: I have edited my answer on the similar question. The edit will work in your case. Cheers